# Adding value to list object in hash-map

Tags: java

I'm trying to add list object to hashmap

I tried with the following code didn't worked

```
public static Map<Long, List<Long>>  getCellAttributes(List<Vo> voList){

    LOG.info("VO: {}", Arrays.toString(VO.toArray()));

    Map<Long, List<Long>> atributesMap = new HashMap();

    List<Long> cellList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(: VOList){
        Long cID = VO.getID();
        Long cellUserNumber = VO.getCellNumber();
        if(cellMap.containsKey(ID)){
            cellList.add(cellNumber);
            cellmap.put(ID, list);
        }
        else {
            Map.put(ID, cellAtributesMap.get(ID).add(cellNumber));
        }
    }
    return cellMao;
}
```

Found below error for else block part.

```
Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'boolean', required:
```

Comment: can anyone please help me, the else block is making me crazy

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first off, what is `Map.put` in the else block? To me it sounds wrong logically, probably you meant the case where the `campaignId`  is not in the map yet.
In this case, you can just:

```
else {
   List<Long> cellList = new ArrayList<>();
   cellList.add(cellUserNumber);
   cellAtributesMap.put(campaignId, cellList);
}
```

Now the `if` block also looks logically wrong, there is no need to maintain a global list (what if the `targetedOffersCampaignVOList` is not ordered) and there is no need to `put` every time into the map.

Since it doesn't seem to be a homework for me, here is a better version:

```
Map<Long, List<Long>> cellAtributesMap = new HashMap();

// note, the following line is not required and should be removed
//List<Long> cellList = new ArrayList<>();

for(TargetedOffersCampaignVO targetedOffersCampaignVO: targetedOffersCampaignVOList){
    Long campaignId = targetedOffersCampaignVO.getCampaignID();
    Long cellUserNumber = targetedOffersCampaignVO.getCellUserNumber();
    if(cellAtributesMap.containsKey(campaignId)){
        // the list in the value already exists anyway, just add a new cell user number to it 
        cellAttributesMap.get(campaignId).add(cellUserNumber);
    }
    else {
        // create a new key-value pair in the result map
        // and add one element which is a current cellUserNumber to it
        List<Long> cellList = new ArrayList<>();
        cellList.add(cellUserNumber);
        cellAtributesMap.put(campaignId, cellList);
    }
}
return cellAtributesMap;
```

Comment: @Bramik it worked, really thanks much for your response

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free accept the answer if you believe it helped to resolve the issue. Its a common practice here in Stack Overflow. Welcome to the community :)

Answer (score 0):

> I think you have problem in your `else` block:

```
else {
         Map.put(campaignId, cellAtributesMap.get(campaignId).add(cellUserNumber));
     }
```

`Map` call here is in inappropirate. If my guess is correct, you want to initialize a new `array` if that particular `campaignId` does not exist in previously, in that case you want to execute this `else` block. Then you just change your `else` block like this:

```
else
{
  List<Long> newList= new ArrayList<>();
  newList.add(cellUserNumber);
  cellAtributesMap.put("campaignId", newList);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cellAtributesMap.get(campaignId).add(cellUserNumber)
```

Above method call returns a boolean value.
Your else block should be like below

```
List<Long> list=new ArrayList<>();//any list implementation
list.add(cellUserNumber);
cellAtributesMap.put(campaignId,list);
```

Comment: @Thanks Girish for the response. Unfortunately you're response will not work for me because If I create new List in the else block the first value will save in the list it will only returns cellList value to hashmap for corresponding hashmap. below example 

1. targetedOffersCampaignVO1.setCampaignID(2l); (this comes to else block for the first time)

2. then later it falls in if block for the same campaignID for different cellusernumber it will get looped and saves with only cellList not with arraylist object.

Comment: simple terms else block list object will get override by the if block cellList object

Comment: from your code what it looks is, you are adding the same value to all the key. is it what you are trying to achieve?